# Add Liquidity to Goerli test network?

Tags: tokens, testnets, goerli

I was wondering how can i add liquidity on goerli test network and check its charts like a mainnet erc20 token , is that possible ?

Comment: I think you should add more context : which charts and which service (e.g. Uniswap ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your wallet to goerli, go on:

https://app.uniswap.org

There you can crete pairs and add liquidity using goerliETH.

Comment: oh i didn't know that , do u know how can i check goerli chart like a mainnet ?

Comment: You can use bitquery. They have support for goerli.

Comment: thank u Rodrigo will check them out :)